# Apex:Datalist showing empty results

Tags: apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I'm trying to show a list of rows from a custom object in a `datalist`.

When I try this on a regular object it seems to work, which is rather strange.

**Controller**

```
     List<Account> accounts;
     public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        if(accounts == null) accounts = [select id from Account limit 10];
        return accounts;
     }
```

**Visualforce**

```
     <apex:dataList value="{!accounts}" var="account" id="theList">
        <apex:outputText value="{!account.id}"/> 
     </apex:dataList>
```

This works just like it use to, it shows the id for all accounts. When I use a custom object I get an empty bullet list. Like:

[image: empty list]

This has the correct amount of bullets (there are 3 items).

**My Controller is now this**

```
     List<AttributeMeetingroomAssociation__c> accounts;
     public List<AttributeMeetingroomAssociation__c> getAccounts() {
        if(accounts == null) accounts = [select id from AttributeMeetingroomAssociation__c limit 10];
        return accounts;

     }
```

`[select id from AttributeMeetingroomAssociation__c limit 10]` gives the 3 correct results when I use them in the salesforce.schema

Anyone has a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you tried to show not id but for example CreatedDate or Name? The same result?

Comment: Yes so weird, exact same result.

Comment: I would say it is a custom object settings for your profile. Read / Write?

Comment: Do you know how i can set these custom objects settings in my profile?

Comment: Go to Setup > Manage Users > Profiles. Over there click on the profile you want to edit. Check "Custom Object Permissions": Your object -> select View All. Then check "Custom Field-Level Security": Your object -> View - these fields must be Visible and not read-only.

Comment: Thanks for that! It was not the solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `<apex:column>` tag to display the results.  For example:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!opportunities}" var="o">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:outputText value="{!o.Name}"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Without the `apex:column` no data is displayed.

Comment: I wanted a datalist to be displayed, not a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Develop site, let check your FLS (Field Level Security) on the field. Go to Setup > Develop > Sites > Site Label > Public Access Settings > Scroll to Custom Field Level Security > Object Name [View] > Edit. Check the "Visible" marks for all fields they should have access to, and save.